# Enabled AuthUsePkce for SwaggerUI but the server returns pkce_missing_challenge

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, okta

I am using version v5.0.0 of Swashbuckle in my asp net core 3.0 app :

```
options.AddSecurityDefinition("OAuth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,

            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
            {
                AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                {
                    AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://my.okta.com/oauth2/v1/authorize"),
                    TokenUrl = new Uri("https://my.okta.com/oauth2/v1/token"),
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                        { "openid", "desc" }
                        },
                }
            },
            Description = "Balea Server OpenId Security Scheme"
        });

app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
            options.RoutePrefix = "docs";
          
            options.OAuthScopeSeparator(",");
            options.OAuthUsePkce();
            });
```

But the Auth server returns error :

pkce_missing_challenge

Here is the request log that Auth server receives :

> /oauth2/v1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8002%2Fdocs%2Foauth2-redirect.html&scope=openid&state=VHVlIE1hciAwMiAyMDIxIDExOjIyOjM3IEdNVCswMDAwIChXZXN0ZXJuIEV1cm9wZWFuIFN0YW5kYXJkIFRpbWUp

Comment: Can you describe your problem in detail and provide more code about your Startup? Are you unable to pass the authorizations or some other problem？

Comment: @Yinqiu my goal is to get accesstoken from okta and provide it for swagger so each time I want to try an endpoint, the accesstoken is passed along the request. I have shared the swagger part of startup, what other part you need to be shared?

Answer (score 0):

So Instead of "Pkce" I used the following configuration thanks to [this](https://devforum.okta.com/t/okta-for-net-and-configure-swagger-to-use-implicit-returns-different-issuer/13211/2?u=bfakhriloo):

```
options.AddSecurityDefinition("OAuth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                {
                    Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                    {
                        AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"mydomain.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize"),
                        TokenUrl = new Uri($"mydomain.com/oauth2/default/v1/token"),
                        Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {
                            { "openid", "test" },
                            },
                    }
                },
            });
```